# Criteria to select the number of neighbors in the k-th-nearest-neighbor density estimation

Tags: clustering, sas, k-nearest-neighbour, density-function

I am doing a cluster analysis based on k-th-nearest-neighbor (KNN) method in SAS. The CLUSTER procedure requires to specify the $k$ (=number of neighbors to use for KNN density estimation) and I was wondering if there is a way or criteria to set the number of neighbors.

Based on the SAS manual,

> *k* th-nearest-neighbor density linkage is strongly set consistent for high-density (density-contour) clusters if $k$ is chosen that
>   $\frac{k}{n} \rightarrow 0$ and $\frac{k}{\ln(n)} \rightarrow \infty$
>   as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Is this answer to my question?
Any good papers on the application of this method will be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can -- and, generally, should always -- do some cross-validation and try out a set of different values for `k` and see what looks best and produces the best results.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but cross-validation is what I've been trying and it can be tedious when there are so many different values to try... I want to know if there is a legitimate way to pick the number of $k$.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. The optimal *k* parameter can vary greatly based on your data. Cross-validation or visual examination of the data is the "legitimate" way.